# Javascript how to add a click event listener in the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i add a click event listener to the body so when i click anywhere within the body the `.arrow-up` and `.login-form` will fade out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arrow = $(".arrow-up");
  var form = $(".login-form");
  var status = false;
  $("#login").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (status == false) {
      arrow.fadeIn();
      form.fadeIn();
      status = true;
    } else {
      arrow.fadeOut();
      form.fadeOut();
      status = false;
    }
  })

  document.getElementByTagName("body").addEventListener('click', function() {
    arrow.fadeOut();
    form.fadeOut();
    status = false;
  });
})
```

Comment: Why not simply bind the event on `body` to make that work? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far handling body click event. Thanks!

Comment: The code you shared is not javascript, its jquery. So thar are you lookng for, javascript or jquery >

Comment: @GabrielAngel if you are into jquery, do `$(document).on('click', function(){ your_fn_ })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such function as `document.getElementByTagName` so

Either use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener('click', function() {console.log('clicked')  });
```

or just:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log('clicked')});
```

And since you anyway use jQuery, you can do

```
$('body').on('click', function(){console.log('clicked')});
```